# Tying PyQt4 QAction triggered() to local class callable doesn't seem to work. How to debug this?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots

I create this object when I want to create a QAction. I then add this QAction to a menu:

```
class ActionObject(object):
  def __init__(self, owner, command):
    action = QtGui.QAction(command.name, owner)
    self.action = action
    self.command = command
    action.setShortcut(command.shortcut)
    action.setStatusTip(command.name)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(action, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.triggered)
  def triggered(self):
    print("got triggered " + self.command.id + " " + repr(checked))
```

Unfortunately, when the menu item is selected, the 'triggered' function is not called.
QtCore.QObject.connect() returns True.
Nothing is printed on the console to indicate that anything is wrong, and no exception is thrown.

How can I debug this? (or, what am I doing wrong?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit late but I had the same problem and I solved it by changing:
`class ActionObject(object)`
to
`class ActionObject()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I can't believe they're using old-style classes, but I gotta go home and try it. While it still doesn't answer the question "how do I actually debug this kind of failure," it does provide a positive way forward, so you get the point!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you adding `action` to any menu in this code (indeed I see no `addAction` call anywhere), and there's a peculiar use of a variable `checked` that is never defined anywhere in your `triggered` method (is it a global defined elsewhere?).  Both of these issues suggest you have other code that you're not showing (the code that adds this action to some menu or toolbar and defines the global variable `checked` -- or did you omit a parameter in the `def triggered` statement, perhaps...?), and that would be where the bugs lie (this code is a *subset* of a potentially correct program... but clearly there are missing parts, and how do we know *they* are correct?-).

Comment: That's not an answer to "how do I debug signals in PyQt4," really...

Yes, the addAction comes from the return value of a function that creates this object. For more code, see

http://pastebin.com/SuKvBLVm

The "checked" variable only matters by the time the slot is called, which doesn't happen, so it's beside the point. (If you want to know, it's a hold-over from when I tried to register the triggered function with the (bool) signature, as per the optional argument in the documentation -- that also didn't work)

So, now that you have all of this information... how do I debug this?

Comment: More information: Connecting to global functions works, it's only connecting to member functions (bound or not) that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your debugging has to occur in one of the two classes you don't provide; where you're attaching attributes to them then passing them to ActionObject as parameters.

I've created an example without this, as I have no idea what your other two classes look like. The third, parent class, I don't need, because of course it can be any generic Class that has inherited QWidget/QMainWindow/QDialog, etc

```
class ActionObject(object):
  def __init__(self, owner=None, command=None):
    self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
    self.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
    # Make sure the menu item's parent is the menu
    self.menuGeneric = QtGui.QMenu(self.menuBar)
    self.menuGeneric.setTitle('&Generic')
    # Create and add the action in one line
    self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuGeneric.menuAction())
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.menuGeneric, qc.SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.triggered)
  def triggered(self):
    print "got triggered"
```

Answer (score 0):

For your two questions:

> 1) How do I debug this?

1) First thing I'd try would be to see if you've got the argument declaration for your function wrong (you have).  To do that, I'd add `*args` and `**kwargs` to your function and then run the code to see if it works:

```
def triggered(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("got triggered " + self.command.id + " " + repr(checked) + " [extra args: {}, kwargs: {}".format(args, kwargs))
```

I bet you'll find you were getting a boolean as the first argument to the function, but your function was declared as not taking any.  The exception was possibly getting logged to stderr or being swallowed.

2) I created a simple decorator to log these types of things for convenience:

```
import functools, sys
def logged_action(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        sys.stderr.write("{}: {}, {}\n".format(func, args, kwargs))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@logged_action
def triggered(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("got triggered " + self.command.id + " " + repr(checked))
```

> 2) (or, what am I doing wrong)

Your connected method doesn't have the right signature, based on my experience with an example I had to hand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[redacted]", line 12, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: triggered() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

`triggered` is being called with self and another argument (hence "2 given"), but you're only declaring you take one.